How can I turn the screen back on using setterm or another command, only with the core utilities over ssh?
I have a Debian 12 system, which is console-only, without a graphical interface / Desktop environmen.
I turned off the screen using setterm --blank force on the device itself, and now I can't turn it back on by pressing a key because force causes keyboard input to be ignored.
I have access via SSH over a Debian 12 Desktop environment, but when I enter setterm -blank 0 through SSH as root, I get the message terminal xterm-256-color does not support --blank.
I also can't switch between different TTYs on the device itself.
Even when I switch to a TTY on the Debian desktop and use setterm --blank 0, I don't get any error message, but nothing happens.
With setterm --blank poke, I get cannot force unblank.
Is there another command from the core utilities that I can use to wake the screen up without installing additional tools?
Otherwise, I'll just reboot.

Does chvt do anything useful?  eg chvt 1 or chvt 2 to change the virtual terminal?  Also maybe useful setterm -blank poke > /dev/tty0 to force setterm to use the display terminal and not the remote session?  Maybe also set TERM=linux ?

To turn the screen back on after it has been turned off with setterm --blank force, you can use the following command from a separate TTY.
Login with ssh on the device and run:
sudo sh -c 'TERM=linux setterm --blank poke </dev/tty1'
sudo Grants superuser privileges

If a user owns a TTY device (like /dev/tty1), there are certain operations that require elevated privileges. This is particularly  for commands that interact directly with hardware or system resources.
The permissions on TTY devices typically allow regular users to read from and write to the device, but certain commands may require root privileges to change settings that could affect the entire system.


Though you might have ownership of the TTY device, running commands that modify terminal behavior typically requires elevated permissions to ensure that the system remains secure and that the user cannot unintentionally disrupt system settings.

On the device itself i can run setterm --blank force to swtich off the screen with e reguals user.
Over ssh when i run setterm --blank force with a regular user,
i receive setterm: cannot force blank: Inappropriate ioctl for device and with
sh -c 'TERM=linux setterm --blank poke </dev/tty1'
or
sh: 1: cannot open /dev/tty2: permission denied
i receive setterm: cannot force blank: Operation not permitted
so i need sudo/root rights to run the command over ssh.

SSH sessions are generally treated with more caution in terms of security. This means that even if the user owns the TTY device, the SSH daemon may enforce additional restrictions that require sudo for commands that could change system behavior or terminal settings.


The permissions for devices like /dev/tty1 are set to allow direct user access, but when accessing through SSH, there might be differences in how permissions are managed.


The requirement for sudo when executing the command over SSH is due to the different permission contexts and security measures for remote sessions compared to local access.

sh -c Executes the enclosed command string in a new shell
TERM=linux Sets the terminal type
setterm --blank poke Uses it to run setterm to wake up the screen with poke
</dev/tty1 Specifies that the input is coming from the first virtual terminal
Short Explanation:
Redirection </dev/tty1 | This specifies that the command is reading from /dev/tty1, which is the first virtual terminal. This is necessary because setterm needs to interact with the console directly
Setting TERM= | TERM=linux is important because it sets the terminal type to linux, ensuring that setterm can correctly interpret the terminal capabilities and perform the required actions
Using sudo |  Requires elevated permissions to interact with the terminal directly, which is why sudo is necessary
And i can switch off the screen now over ssh with:
sudo sh -c 'TERM=linux setterm --blank force </dev/tty1'
Edit:
It seems that it doesn't matter whether I use tty1, tty4, or any other ttyX in the command it still works with
</dev/tty4 etc..

Kernel Handling of Virtual Terminals The Linux kernel manages multiple virtual terminals (TTYs), and they all share similar characteristics. When you use setterm with a specified TTY (e.g., /dev/tty1), it can control the screen settings of that terminal, but it doesn't restrict the command to only that specific terminal.
Since the command doesn't rely on the current terminal but on the input redirection, you can effectively target any TTY without issue.
Setting TERM=linux ensures that setterm understands how to interact with the terminal, regardless of which TTY you're targeting.


OK, the quotes seem somewhat insightful. What is the source of these quotes?
